# Disable onboard WiFi & Bluetooth Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: wifi, wireless-adapter

I want to disable the onboard Wi-Fi & Bluetooth, so as to connect an external Wi-Fi adapter on it for Hotspot configuration.

Since I searched on the internet, I find that we have to edit a blacklist file : `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`   and we should add the configuration below.

## Wi-Fi

```
 blacklist brcmfmac
 blacklist brcmutil
```

## Bluetooth

```
blacklist btbcm
blacklist hci_uart
```

Since I do this, my hotspot on my external adapter is not working anymore but when I `ifconfig` I see the `wlan0` of my adapter...

Is there a better option to disable the internal Wi-Fi ?

Comment: Have you tried `ifconfig wlan0 down; ifconfig wlan1 up;`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way.

You can edit **/boot/config.txt** and add this two lines:

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
dtoverlay=disable-bt
```

After reboot, WiFi & Bluetooth will be fully disabled.

More info on: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README

Comment: Does disabling WiFi and Bluetooth "reduce the energy footprint" of the Pi further?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, it does but it is hard to know how much the consumption is reduced. To have an accurate value an external device between the power supply and rpi should be used.