# Where are the wireless & bluetooth modules located on the RaspberryPi 3? In order to remove them to disable wifi and bluetooth

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, wireless, bluetooth

As i would like to desolder or cut the traces leading to these modules, in order for the wifi and the bluetooth to not work anymore, could someone please help me and tell me where these two models are located?

And if possible - can you also tell me which traces i need to cut for the wifi and the bluetooth to not work anymore while leaving the rest of the raspberry pi still functioning?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing why you want to do this, I would suggest you consider either switching to a Pi2 which does not have WiFi or Bluetooth or [disabling the modules via software](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/disable-onboard-wifi-bluetooth-raspberry-pi-3?rq=1).

If you are adamant that you want to void your warranty, you can view the [schematics for the Pi3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-3B-V1.2-Schematics.pdf) to determine the best method of disabling them.